# how to move into multiple json objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i wrote a login page code in js that runs on node express.js server and anyone can put their username /email and password and all that data goes into an json file and it looks like this

```
{"username":"admin","password":"pasword","email":"user@stackoverflow.com","timestamp":1598668572045,"_id":"dx8HqKkVWe8olH5z"}
```

i managed to get the timestamp and NeDB gives a random _id to that object.
and when you login you go to a home page that looks like this
[image: simple home page of mine]

but the user gets the username value when there is on object only on the database which is "database.json"
if there is more than 1 object on the database that action will crash and the client can't see his name or any thing it shows nothing .
i don't know how to make it work with several objects on the database.
i thought JSON.parse Or stringfy could make it work but i don't know how to use them on my case.
so here is the js code

```
var jsonn = '/database.json';

async function userinfo() {
    
    const response = await fetch(jsonn);
    const data = await response.json();
    var { username, password } = data;
    
    
    document.getElementById('user').textContent = username;
    
    
    console.log (data)
    console.log (username);
    console.log (id);
}

userinfo();
```

i appreciate any help, if you got any idea please share it with me i really need your help.

UPDATE :
the error message says :
uncaught (in promise) syntaxError : unxpected token in json positon 126.

my server.js code :

```js
const Datastore = require('nedb');
app.listen(2000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.static('/public'));
app.use(express.json({
    limit: '1mb'
}));
const database = new Datastore('public/database.json');
database.loadDatabase();
app.post('/public', (request, response) => {
    const data = request.body;
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    data.timestamp = timestamp;
    database.insert(data);
    response.json(data);
    console.log(data);
    var logdate = new Date;
    console.log(logdate);
});
```

Comment: In the server are you querying the database by the user data they provide? If so, the user data needs to be unique or you will get an array depending on how you query the db. Per the above description, it seems that you are returning all of the database.json which appears to be an array which is probs why it fails when trying to destructure the username, password parameters from data. If you provide an actual error message and sample database.json output returned, then we will be able to help more.

Comment: i will update the error message and how the server query the db in the post above

Comment: Did you try updating, `textContent` to `innerHTML`

Comment: it couldn't even console.log the data so i know the problem is when a new object enters the database

Comment: i just need a way to read multiple objects 'i guess'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some issues with the way that you are calling the DB insert. Basically, on every post request, you allow an insert. This is causing you to have multiple users with the same username. When you search for users by username then you will get a bunch of users. Instead, you want something like the sample code below.

I removed the status public to make it easier to test so make sure to add it back in so you can test front end code. Right now there's just a GET request endpoint so you can get the data by username through a query. This requires more cleanup and checks but at least it will get you started. Also, I remove the password and DB _id from the response as this is probs data you don't want to send back. Ideally, you will encrypt the password before storing it in DB.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Datastore = require('nedb');
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.json({
    limit: '1mb'
}));
const database = new Datastore('public/database.json');
database.loadDatabase();

app.get('/public', (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.query;
  database.findOne({
    username,
  }, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.sendStatus(500);
    }
    delete user._id;
    delete user.password;

    return res.json(user);
  });
});

app.post('/public', (req, res) => {
    const data = req.body;
    const {
      username
    } = data;

    database.findOne({ 
      username,
    }, (err, user) => {
      if(err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }
      if(user) {
        delete newUser._id;
        delete newUser.password;
        return res.json(user) 
      }

      data.timestamp = Date.now();
      database.insert(data, (createError, newUser) => {
        if(createError) {
          return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        delete newUser._id;
        delete newUser.password;
        res.json(newUser);
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: i will handle the errors later but i can get the data base and i see that from the console but i don't want to change the server code yet it's client code problem it cannot read more than 1 json object so i guess i will give eache user a personal database

Comment: If you don't want to change server code. Then just get the first element that matches the username by parsing the data array returned in front end. const userArr = data.find(val => val.username === username); Then just grab the first element and destructure your data from there.  var { username, password } = userArr[0]. Make sure to handle checking whether userArr has any elements on it before grabbing the first element. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for helping me on this i will try the second solution it seems to fit well.